# How would I use reflection to call all the methods that has a certain custom attribute?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, methodinfo

I have a class with a bunch of methods.

some of these methods are marked by a custom attribute.

I would like to call all these methods at once.

How would I go about using reflection to find a list of all the methods in that class that contains this attribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you get the list of methods, you would cycle query for the custom attributes using the GetCustomAttributes method. You may need to change the BindingFlags to suit your situation.

```
var methods = typeof( MyClass ).GetMethods( BindingFlags.Public );

foreach(var method in methods)
{
    var attributes = method.GetCustomAttributes( typeof( MyAttribute ), true );
    if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
        //method has attribute.

}
```

Answer (score 6):

First, you would call [typeof(MyClass).GetMethods()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx) to get an array of all the methods defined on that type, then you loop through each of the methods it returns and call [methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to get an array of custom attributes of the specified type. If the array is zero-length then your attribute is not on the method. If it's non-zero, then your attribute is on that method and you can use [MethodInfo.Invoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to call it.