# How to get custom a list of methods with reflection in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, unity-container, bindingflags

I have being using reflection to create a list of methods that the user would use in a dynamic generated menu (I'am in unity). I'am using:

```
MethodInfo[] methodInfos =  myObject.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

But not all public methods of the class should appear in this menu, so I was wondering, is there some flag which I could use to mark only the methods that I need?

And then use this "custom flag" to get those methods through reflection. Thanks :).

Comment: mark methods which you need with custom attribute

Answer (score 7):

Use custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MenuItemAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

and allow user to mark methods:

```
public class Foo
{
    [MenuItem]
    public void Bar() {}
}
```

Then, on methods lookup, inspect metadata for this attribute:

```
var methodInfos = myObject
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
    .Where(_ => _.IsDefined(typeof(MenuItemAttribute)));
```

If you need to provide an ability for user to define menu path, then extend your attribute with custom parameter, something like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MenuItemAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MenuItemAttribute(string menuPath)
    {
        MenuPath = menuPath;
    }

    public string MenuPath { get; }
}
```

Another option is to throw away custom way to make plugins, and use something out of the box, e.g., [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Hey, thanks ! Great answer ! However I don't have a definition for the "Where Method", what I'am missing ? System.Reflection.MethodInfo[]' does not contain a definition for `Where'

Comment: Well I suppose that the API changes from the Unity C# version and .NET C#, I finally solved this with this SO answer:

[How would I use reflection...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831809/how-would-i-use-reflection-to-call-all-the-methods-that-has-a-certain-custom-att)

But your answer was very helpful and got me on the right track, thanks @Dennis

Comment: This is the extension method from System.Linq namespace. It's not related to Unity API.

Answer (score 2):

You could used below code. It will returns both public as well non public methods.

```
MethodInfo[] methodInfos =  myObject.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```