# Get only the parent fields from an inherited class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

I have a class called Stats

```
public class Stats : ScriptableObject
{
    public double vitality;   
    public double stamina;     
    public double endurance; 
}
```

I also have a class that inherits Stats

```
public class Equipment : Stats
{
    public string name;
    // other fields that define equipment
}
```

I want to be able to get all the fields from the instance of Stats that is inherited from Equipment

So I added this in an Interface class

```
    public void AddStats(Equipment equippedItem)
    {
        Stats stats = equippedItem as Stats;
        if (stats != null)
        {
            GetPropertyValues(stats);
        }
    }
   public static void GetPropertyValues(System.Object obj)
   {
        Type t = obj.GetType();
        FieldInfo[] fis = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var fieldInfo in fis)
                Debug.Log(fieldInfo.FieldType + " " + fieldInfo.Name + " " + fieldInfo.GetValue(obj));
   }
```

The issue is that it is getting all the fields from the Equipment as well.

How could I make it so that only gets the fields from Stats?

Comment: You could try using t.BaseType

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
Type t = obj.GetType();
```

but pass in your target type

```
typeof(Stats);
```

You could have an overload for this use case and have e.g.

```
public static void GetPropertyValues(System.Object obj, Type type)
```

and add a check if the given `obj` is of type `type` or a subclass

```
var objType = obj.GetType();
if(objType != type && !objType.IsSubclassOf(type))
{
    throw ArgumentException($"Provided object of type {objType.Name} is not derived from {type.Name}");
}
```

Or the same as a generic

```
public static void GetPropertyValues<Ttype>(System.Object obj)
```

and

```
var objType = obj.GetType();
var type = typeof(T);
if(objType != type && !objType.IsSubclassOf(type))
{
    throw ArgumentException($"Provided object of type {objType.Name} is not derived from {type.Name}");
}
```

Reflection is never going to be "beautiful" ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution here [How to get custom a list of methods with reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32325159/how-to-get-custom-a-list-of-methods-with-reflection-in-c-sharp)
so I created a attribute called stat

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class Stat : Attribute {}
```

And I added this attribute to all the variables I wanted to get in my Stats class:

```
    public class Stats : ScriptableObject
    {
        [Stat] public double vitality;   
        [Stat] public double stamina;     
        [Stat] public double endurance; 
    }
```

Then I updated my `GetPropertyValues` method to pick up the attributes and added it to an array.

```
   public static void GetPropertyValues(System.Object obj, double[] array)
   {
        // Getting the class
        Type t = obj.GetType();
        // Getting all the fields(Variables)
        FieldInfo[] fis = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.ExactBinding | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        int arrayLength = 0;
        // Iterating over all fields (variables)
        for (int i = 0; i < fis.Length; i++) 
        {
            // Filtering through the list and if the field(Variable) is marked with a Stat attribute adds it to array length
            arrayLength += i;
        }

        array = new double[arrayLength];

        // Iterating over all the fields (variables)
        for (int i = 0; i < fis.Length; i++) 
        {
            // Filtering through the list and if the field(Variable) is marked with a Stat attribute ....
            Stat attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fis[i], typeof(Stat)) as Stat;

            if (attribute != null)
            {
                Debug.Log(fis[i].Name + " " + fis[i].GetValue(obj)); // The name of the flagged variable.
                array[i] = (Convert.ToDouble(fis[i].GetValue(obj)));
                Debug.Log(array[i]);
            }
        }
   }
```